# Vuejs appending html after click on element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a table that fills with data from json. So how i can append a new  after cllicked element ?

```
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="f in firm" class="main" >
            <td id="ccc">{{ f.name.toUpperCase() }}</td>
            <td>{{ f.open }}</td>
            <td>{{ f.max }}</td>
            <td>{{ f.min }}</td>
            <td>{{ f.close }}</td>
            <td>{{ f.change }}</td>
            <td>{{ f.trans }}</td>
            <td>{{ f.vol }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
```

This code creata for me my table with data And now i want to click one element and after this element append new tr. I try create methods but every my idea wail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the data that your HTML is rendering, the HTML will update automatically. Since the code renders a `<tr>` for each item in the `firm` array, add an item to the `firm` array to make a new `<tr>`. See the demo below.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    firm: []
  },
  methods: {
    addRow() {
      this.firm.push({
        name: 'new row',
        open: 'open',
        max: 'max',
        min: 'min',
        close: 'close',
        change: 'change',
        trans: 'trans',
        vol: 'vol',
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <button @click="addRow">Add new row</button>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="f in firm" class="main">
        <td id="ccc">{{ f.name.toUpperCase() }}</td>
        <td>{{ f.open }}</td>
        <td>{{ f.max }}</td>
        <td>{{ f.min }}</td>
        <td>{{ f.close }}</td>
        <td>{{ f.change }}</td>
        <td>{{ f.trans }}</td>
        <td>{{ f.vol }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
```

Comment: ok but wha if i want to ad with custom <tr> e.g <tr><td colspan=3></td><td colspan=2></td><td colspan=2></td></tr>

Comment: Add the appropriate properties to your data, maybe a `colspan` property for each item in the `firm` array, then have your template access that property, like `<td :colspan="f.colspan">...</td>`